# Apartment field bug?

Tags: addresses

I have CiviCRM 5.28.0. I have parsed my addresses to separate in door number, street name and apt.

My problem is that when I enter data in the fields, it does not save it as it should. More precisely, if I enter the following information:

Door number: 123
Street Address: ABC
Apt: 4

And save. When I reopen the contact page, the address is saved as:

Door number: 123
Street Address: ABC 4
Apt:

That is the Apt is saved in the Street Field.

Is this a bug or something I overlooked?

Although I do not think it has an influence on the problem, I am using CiviCRM with Joomla.

Thank you for your input on this matter.

Judith